# SQLite connection won't work

Tags: java, sqlite

I've looked through a lot of other questions about this but none seem to work for me. I even have the SQLite.jar resource in my build path. Can someone provide me with the proper download link for it? Maybe I have the wrong one. But It always gives connection failure errors.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      Class.forName("SQLite.JDBCDriver");
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/Users/mac/Desktop/database.db");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Gives me

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JBDC
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
at SQLTest.Main.main(Main.java:25)
```

Comment: can you please post the stack trace of the error?

Comment: Put `SQLite.jar` in your runtime classpath rather than in your project build path

Comment: I just went to my Run>Classpath and saw that it's in there. And still get that error. Not sure why it's doing this.

Comment: NVM fixed! Downloaded newer version and it works.